# MVC with user-defined (data driven) form definitions

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

As an example, formstack.com and wufoo.com etc- To implement a data-driven form definition framework inside ASP.Net MVC, I assume you wind up tossing out a lot of the built-in features (model binding, attribute based validation, etc) and replace them with data-driven equivalents.

I'm curious if there are best practices for using MVC in this data-driven fashion, and perhaps some code or frameworks to assist with this type of application?

Comment: I dug around a while back for this type of thing but didn't find much,  which was a little surprising - I think I'll try again.  Providing users with customize-able forms would seem like a fairly common requirement, and you'd think there would be tools like this.  I will watch this to see if anyone has some suggestions.

Comment: http://formfactory.apphb.com/ - seems interesting.  Not quite data-driven but renders forms from POCOS, some interesting capabilities...

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082008-1.aspx try doing something like this with MVC

Answer (score 0):

The hook where I see in ASP.NET MVC would be Html.EditorFor.  You can have the model specify the view that will render the data.

```
@model IEnumerable<ParentClass>

@for (int i = 1; i <= Model.length; i++)
{
    Html.EditorFor(Model(i),Model(i).ViewName)
}
```

View1.cshtml

```
@model ChildClass
@Model.FieldName: <input id="@Html.IdFor(model=>model)" type="text" name="@Model.FieldName"><br>
```

View2.cshtml

```
@model ChildClass
@Model.FieldName: <input id="@Html.IdFor(model=>model)" type="password" name="@Model.FieldName"><br>
```

You then specify View1 or View2 in your data.

Note: The reason I used a for loop and not a foreach is MVC needs the index to get the id in the editor right.